# How to Extract Name and email from website in php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract all Faculty Name and Email Address from the webpage using **file_get_contents();**. But I not very good at regular expressions. Can any body Please help me me out for this. Here is the webpage link from where I want to extract Faculty name and email address

http://umt.edu.pk/Academics/Faculty.aspx

Below is the code what I have done so far...

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('http://umt.edu.pk/Academics/Faculty.aspx');
$regex = '#<div class=\"staff\"><div><h4>(.*)</h4></div></div>#';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
echo $match[0];
?>
```

Please help me out to extract all Faculty name and email addresses from the given link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need a non-greedy regex `'#<div class=\"staff\"><div><h4>(.*?)</h4></div></div>#'`

Comment: don't parse html files with regex.

Comment: http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can You please modify my code using regular expression .

Answer (score 0):

You can try X-Path :

For name:
      [@div="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-9 colxs9"]/h4

and for Email :
             [@div="col-lg-8 col-md-9 col-sm-9 colxs9"]/p/a

i hope this will help you